# Is there website that allows to interact with smart contract using only ABI in a generic way?

Tags: remix, contract-invocation

I have ABI for a contract but do not have source code. Is there any website or application which uses the ABI and deployed contract address to interact with the contract.

I have tried [myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/interface/interact-with-contract) but it seems that link is broken now.
Is there any way in remix to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually go with https://oneclickdapp.com/ when I need to do quick-testings for dapps